# How to loop through all elements in a div and find tags that contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to loop through a div that contains all kind of elements.
The problem is, that I get the same results showing up in my example.

Here is the fiddle with the example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/JLtCN/

So the html structure of my example looks like:

```
<div class="somediv">
    <span>hello</span>
    <img src="someimg.jpg" width="20" height="20" />
    <p></p>
    <div><p>some text in a paragraph inside a div</p></div>
    <h2>Some h2 tekst</h2>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>some text in a table cell</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My goal was to get all the content inside the html tags. like so,

```
tagtype: <span>, text: 'hello',
tagtype: <p>, text: 'some text in a paragraph inside a div'
etc.
```

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: It's not clear to me what it is you want to achieve. Have you tried just calling `$('.somediv').text()`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.somediv *').each(function() {
    var hastext = $(this).text().length != 0;
    if(hastext) {
        console.log("type: " + $(this)[0].tagName + " text: " + $(this).text());
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JLtCN/1/

**If you want to get rid of the dupes, simply store the logged items in an array and then check if it's not in the array before logging, something like:**

**Also, it now does them in reverse order so you get the lowest child instances only**:

```
var addedItems = new Array();

$.each($('.somediv *').toArray().reverse(), function() {
    var hastext = $(this).text().length != 0;
    if(hastext && addedItems.indexOf($.trim($(this).text())) == -1) {
        addedItems.push($.trim($(this).text()));
        console.log("type: " + $(this)[0].tagName + " text: " + $(this).text());
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JLtCN/3/

Comment: Also, OP can consider using objects to store the tagname and the inner text, and push them into an array when going through the `.each()` loop.

Comment: @Terry Yeah I thought about that for preventing dupes.

Comment: I'm thinking of something along the line of: `tags.push({'tagType':$(this).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase(), 'tagText':$(this).text()});`, and one has to declare an empty array, `var tags = []` before calling the `.each()` function.

Comment: You could also try this if repeating child elements are an issue: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: Thanks mattytommo :) great solution, the only thing was that you don't know what element contains the text. for example, if I now use the solution of Terry you can't see that the p tag containted the text some text inside a paragraph inside a div.  It tells that the div element contains the this text. But I would like to find it at the p level.

Comment: @user1506394 That's easy, we can just reverse the list, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/JLtCN/3/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var seenStrings = [],
    content = $.map(
        $(".somediv *"),
        function(element) {
            var text = $(element).text();
            if ($.inArray(text, seenStrings) !== -1) {
              return {
                  tagname: "<" + element.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ">",
                  text: $(element).text()
              };
            } else {
              return null;
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: great one! this is almost what i was looking for. In here I have
to take care of the duplicates. Only, you can't know this way if the innertext belongs to the <p> paragraph, or to the <div> that contains the paragraph. Because jQuery tells that $('.somediv div').text()  is the same as $('.somediv div p').text();

Comment: hello mikez302, I tried your new answer, but it does not seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mRMM9/

Answer (score 1):

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 1){
        document.write(node.nodeName + ": " );
    }        
    if(node.nodeType == 3){
        document.write(node.nodeValue +" <br/>");
    }
});
```

Comment: 'nodeType === 3' is text, more here on the [TextNode object](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkuedch.php)

Comment: The solution of PHearst is the closest one. Because here i can see what element has text inside it, without the duplicates.
I only needed to change the function a little bit like so:
(giving the div an id) and passing it to that function.

http://jsfiddle.net/QjhjS/

Comment: Please be kind to all and tick the answer you find most useful.